# R read csv with observations in colums

Tags: r, variables, read.csv

in every example I have seen so far for reading csv files in R, the variables are in columns and the observations (individuals) are in rows. In a introductory statistics course I am taking there is an example table where the (many) variables are in rows and the (few) observations are in columns. Is there a way to read such a table so that you get a dataframe in the usual "orientation"?

Comment: Use `t()` after reading the data

Comment: It's hard to do anything but guess without seeing your data or code or what you've been able to do so far. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses the tidyverse. First, we gather the data into narrow format tidy data, then we spread it back to wide format, setting the first column as a key for the gathered observations by excluding it from `gather()`.

We'll demonstrate the technique with state level summary data from the [U.S. Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/quickfacts/fact/table/CA,AK,AL,GA/PST045218).

I created a table of population data for four states, where the states (observations) are in columns, and the variables are listed in rows of the table.

[image]

To make the example reproducible, we entered the data into Excel and saved it as a comma separated values file, which we assign to a vector in R and read with `read.csv()`.

```
textFile <- "Variable,Georgia,California,Alaska,Alabama
population2018Estimate,10519475,39557045,737438,4887871
population2010EstimatedBase,9688709,37254523,710249,4780138
pctChange2010to2018,8.6,6.2,3.8,2.3
population2010Census,8676653,37253956,710231,4779736"

# load tidyverse libraries 
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
# first gather to narrow format then spread back to wide format
data %>% 
     gather(.,state,value,-Variable) %>% spread(Variable,value)
```

...and the results:

```
       state pctChange2010to2018 population2010Census
1    Alabama                 2.3              4779736
2     Alaska                 3.8               710231
3 California                 6.2             37253956
4    Georgia                 8.6              8676653
  population2010EstimatedBase population2018Estimate
1                     4780138                4887871
2                      710249                 737438
3                    37254523               39557045
4                     9688709               10519475
```